# Change dojox.charting.Chart title after render

Tags: php, javascript, charts, dojo

I was wondering if there is any method from which we can set title of a Chart after it is rendered. The title can be set initially while creating the chart object, example:

```
var chart = new dojox.charting.Chart("test", {
      title: "Production(Quantity)"
});

...

chart.render();
```

But after its rendered, how can I change the title. I have tried chart.setTitle("New Name");
and chart.set("title","New Name"); but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Which version of Dojo?

Comment: 1.8.3 Thanks but I got the answer. We can access the property directly like chart.title = "new title"; and then re-render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/eSXyv/) seems to work. Set the `title` field directly (there doesn't appear to be a setter method), and then call `fullRender()`.

This code is the crux of it:

```
    query("#changetitle").onclick(function () {
        // These 3 don't work
        //c.setTitle("Two");
        //c.setChartTitle("Two");
        //c.set("title", "Two");
        chart.title = new Date().toString();
        chart.fullRender();
    });
```